# How to optimize Google places autocomplete requests from android application

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have an android application which uses "Google places autocomplete api". Whenever an user types a character in the textbox, it makes a request to the api and gets the "places" details. Everything is working fine. But i have hit a problem!

Since there a limit on number of free requests per day, i am not sure how to keep it within the limit! I think the maximum requests (quota) is 150000 per 24 hours.

1. How do others manage to keep it within the limit?
2. What strategy do you use?
3. Do you cache the places data? I know google says you should not cache data but in one of the other google document it says, to stay within the limits, you can cache the data for a maximum of 28 or 30 days!

Note: Since my application would be used in many common places, i am pretty sure the quota will be hit within couple of hours each day!

Comment: If your app is going to be popular you're going to hit the limit-  they want you to.  They want to charge you for using the service.  Thus the no caching policy.  But if you read the actual terms of service you see they mean no permanent caching (like saving the results into your own database so you can avoid calling them in the future), not that you can't save the results from a few minutes ago.

Comment: So does it mean that i would definitely be charged? I cant do any optimisation to keep myself within limits?

Comment: You can optimize, but telling you how to without knowing your app is hard. But if you actually become popular you will absolutely be charged. They only provide a small amount free to drum up business, they want to make money on this data. That's why the request rate for free usage is set low enough that you'll hit it eventually

Comment: I see! My app is simple. I have a map with a "search text box". Users starts typing the city name, let say "London". For each character typed, it makes a request to google to populate the dropdown below the text box with the appropriate address. So for this example , it would have made 5 requests to google. So if 100 devices were making the same search, then its going to be 5*100 requests since my device (android app) talks to google api directly.

Comment: I was wondering that if  my android app makes the request to my very own server and my server can call google api? I was thinking that i will implement a caching strategy on my server. So for example, if android-app-1 searches for "London" through my server, it would account for 5 requests. Now if other device, lets say android-app-2 makes the same search, i dont have to make a request to google since i have cached data.

Would this work?

Comment: It would work technically, although it would be slower. You'll have two network latencies per request instead of one. I also suspect the Google  api likely does it's own look ahead caching for speed although I don't know for sure. But whether this is a tos violation- possibly. Close to the line, depending on how long you cache. If this is for a business, I'd talk top a lawyer if this is an important feature you couldn't cut I'd they sent you a c&d.

Comment: I'd also advise you- abstract this out from your app logic so you could replace it with a competitor's data stream. It's never a good idea to be reliant on someone else's data without a backup plan. And there are other location data providers, including open source data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104090/discussion-between-user3807940-and-gabe-sechan).